# How do I drag down complex calculations in open office.

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, openoffice-calc

For example if A1 contains 30 and in A2 I write `=A1-6` then I'll get 27 in A2 and if I click the little black squair in the lower right hand corner of A2 and drag it down then I get a column that looks like this:

```
30
27
24
21
18
15
12
```

And so on.

If I try to do this with a formula of multiple variables though then it won't work. For example if I instead type in A2 `= (A1 - B1)*C1` and drag that down in the same way then the next cell will have the formula `= (A2 - B2)*C2`. But I only want the A# to get incremented.

How do I do this?

Comment: The "$" before a letter(column) or number (row) will prevent it from auto incrementing.  "$a$2" will never increment at all. "a$2" the column only increments.  "$a2" the row only increments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$" before a letter(column) or number (row) will prevent it from auto incrementing. "$a$2" will never increment at all. "a$2" the column only increments. "$a2" the row only increments

```
type in A2 = (A1 - B1)*C1
 I only want the A# to get incremented
        a2 = ($a1-$b$1)*$c$1
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. How would I do it if I have a date in A1 and I want each subsequent cell in the column to increment by one month?

Comment: =A8+DAYSINMONTH(A8)  Substitute the cell with the first date in it for A8, and place the formula in the next cell or A9 in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Macro for you:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Main


End Sub


sub arg
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "ToPoint"
args1(0).Value = "$A$4"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args1())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args2(0).Name = "StringName"
args2(0).Value = "30"


dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:EnterString", "", 0, args2())
dim args4(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue

for a=0 to 100
args1(0).Name="ToPoint"
args1(0).Value="a"+(a+4)

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:JumpToNextCell", "", 0, Array())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------

args4(0).Name = "StringName"
args4(0).Value = "="&30-(3*a)


dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:EnterString", "", 0, args4())
next a
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------

end sub
```

Comment: I don't know how they did it, but someone's managed to make a language worse than VBA.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  I have to agree they succeed in making an awful programming language.